# Actualizar datos de un usuario en una sección conectada a base de datos

Tags: php, pdo

Hola quiero actualizar los datos de usuario que estan en una base de datos 
el usuario esta conectado mediante una $_SESSION['user'];

probe usando este codigo pero no se actualiza ninguna variable

> ademas trate de que el avatar no se obligatorio para la actualización de datos pero no lo logre

```
<?php
require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$password = specialtext($_POST['password']);
$password = hash('sha512', $password);
$avatar = $_POST['avatar'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");
  //$conexion->set_charset('utf8mb4');
  $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE user SET pasword= $password,tipo='user',avatar=$avatar WHERE id = $id");

}
header("Location: /");
 ?>
```

este es mi formulario

```
<form action="" method="post">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="<?php echo $user;?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" readonly name="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" value="<?php echo $pass;?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Avatar</label>
              <input type="file" disabled readonly name="avatar" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" disabled name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Actualizar</button>
        </form>
```

Esta es mi tabla en la base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pasword` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bloqueado` int(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando consultas preparadas, y como tales, después de prepararlas necesitas ejecutarlas, prueba así.

```
$sentencia = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE user SET pasword=:password, tipo=:tipo, avatar=:avatar WHERE id=:id");
$sentencia->execute(array(':password' => $password, ':tipo' => 'user', ':avatar' => $avatar, ':id' => $id));
```

[Documentación de la función execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)